# Send different email content with $mail php

Tags: php, email

I have a small problem here that I'm tried to fix for some couple of hours already. I have a PHP `$mail` function that send emails to multiple addresses using PHP for loop, like:

```
foreach($recipients as $name => $email){
    $mail->AddAddress($email, $name);
};
```

**Problem is:**

I need to get inside the Body message, each email from each user at the time of sending the message, so I can use it as variable inside the body message, I've already tried to use another `foreach` inside, but no luck.

So the PHP will be something like this:

```
$mail->Body .='Start of the message';
$mail->Body .='path_url?user_email='.$recipient.'';
$mail->Body .='Endof the message';
```

Is this possible using `$mail`?

Thanks!

Comment: You should use the same for loop and put every thing inside.

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥıλɐɯ, Hey mate, it worked, place an answer so i can accept it, thanks a lot!

Comment: mate and here is my welcome vote up. Cool, I am happy that it worked for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the same for loop for both email addresses and your content.

With out knowing your code in details, I assume you have array contenting recipients email, name and message or something else.

Some thing like this with out testing it:

```
foreach ($recipients as $value)
{
    $mail->AddAddress($value['email'], $value['name']);
    $mail->Body .= 'Start of the message';
    $mail->Body .= 'path_url?user_email=' . $value['recipient'];
    $mail->Body .= 'Endof the message';
    ...
    the rest of your $mail code if there so
    ...
};
```